# Why is jquery document.ready running twice when re-rendering a visualforce component within a page?

Tags: jquery, salesforce, apex, visualforce

I have the following Visualforce page which contains a component within an `<apex:outputPanel>`:

```
<apex:page docType="html-5.0" controller="Test1Controller">
    <c:ContainerStart header="false" pageTitle="Test 1" />
    <apex:form>
        <apex:outputPanel id="container" layout="inline">
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>

            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!shouldDisplay}" layout="none">
                <c:Test1 />
            </apex:outputPanel>

        </apex:outputPanel>

        <input type="button" onclick="causeRerender()" value="Rerender" />

        <apex:actionFunction name="causeRerender" action="{!doRerender}" rerender="container" />
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

In the component, there is just a `console.log` for when the component loads:

```
<apex:component id="Test1">

    <h2>Component</h2>

    <script>
        $(function() {
            console.log('ready!')
        });
    </script>

</apex:component>
```

I have noticed a strange behaviour when the component is made to rerender by clicking on the button. The component rerenders correctly, however the code in the onload function runs twice.

ie: The console log when the page loads is:
[image: first screenshot]

Then after clicking the button, two more messages are added to the log:
[image]

I can't see any reason that it should run twice. It is causing havoc in some pages where the onload code should only be run once.

Update: I have discovered that if I change the display in the `<apex:outputPanel` from `none` to `inline`, then the re-render will only call the code once, as expected.

Comment: In your console, is all the "ready!" coming from the same line? to the right of the "ready!" you should be able to see a line number

Comment: Have updated the screenshot with the line numbers. The first one is when the page loads, and is running from the component. The other two are from the re-render. Not sure why the source code is reporting different lines to that of the initial load

Comment: Well I guess then you get multiple "Ready!" because of the render. It's logic, because you load/hide the "content/code" again and again

Comment: I would expect though, to only see 2 'ready!' messages. Once when the page loads, and then another time when the re-render is triggered. Also see the update note above, if the display attribute is changed in the outputPanel, then this is exactly what happens. Why is it calling it twice when `display="none"`?